# Updated to Xcode 4.5, landscape orientation isn't working and none of the proposed solutions have fixed the issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have a landscape only app, and when I run the simulator, the device is rotated to landscape mode, but the screen is trying to display in portrait mode.

Here are the steps I've already tried

My root view controller is a navigation controller, so I subclassed it and added

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

return YES;
}
```

I also tried doing that to individual view controllers, but no result.

This is what I have in the app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

home = [[Home alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home" bundle:nil];
navController = [[NavControllerSubClass alloc] initWithRootViewController:home];
[self.window setRootViewController:navController];
 //  used to be [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;

}
```

Any other solutions?

Comment: Well, the right way to use a custom view controller subclass is to set its Custom Class in the storyboard editor. Try that first.

Comment: i created the app before storyboard came out, so I don't think my app actually has it

Answer (score 1):

I changed `return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape` to `return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft` and it works fine. Not sure why though.